# error with discord.js when reading .env variables

Tags: javascript, discord.js, environment-variables

I'm using discord.js to learn java script, but I'm having a problem with variables stored in .env

apparently they are not being read correctly; and honestly, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong because I don't really know how it works.

my variable in .env is written like this:

```
TOKEN = xxXxxXXXXxXXXxXXXxXXxXXX
LOG_CHANNEL = 1071616980039249920
```

i know dotenv is working fine because this line works perfectly:
`client.login(process.env.TOKEN)`

while I have this line in index.js:

```
client.channels.cache.get(process.env.LOG_CHANNEL).send({
            embeds: [
                // random embed here
            ]
        })
```

and i receive this error:

```
        client.channels.cache.get(process.env.LOG_CHANNEL).send({
                                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
```

but it works perfectly when i change it to:

```
client.channels.cache.get('1071616980039249920').send({
            embeds: [
                // random embed here
            ]
        })
```

I tried changing the way the code is written in the .env by adding ` to the variable declaration, but apparently it didn't make any difference.

I'm looking for a way to make this work, as this snippet in index.js recurs frequently and I plan to change the log channel a few times.

Also, I would love a basic explanation of how these declarations work in the .env: are they all considered strings, even without quotes?

Comment: btw im using discord.js@14.7.1

Comment: Are you sure you have the dotenv library installed and you have configured it properly?

Comment: yes! i will add the token snippets in the question to ensure everyone get this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables from `.env` file are not loaded into Node by default. You can use npm package `dotenv` to load the variables from the file.

To do so, install the package:

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

Then, in your main file, at the beginning, add the following code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

After this line of code is called, your variables from `.env` file are available as properties of `process.env`, i.e. `process.env.LOG_CHANNEL`. They are of string type. If you want to use them as numbers, you need to convert them in your code.

Also, you might need to keep your variables in `.env` without additional spaces and with quotes:

```
LOG_CHANNEL="1071616980039249920"
```

Comment: i already had the dotenv installed and included, but yea. it was just a formatting issue. i didnt know i had to add quotes to the channel id because i didnt add it to the token and it works perfectly